# How to remove a child node with a null parent node in XML

Tags: xml, linq, wix

I've come across a unique situation where I need to remove an XElement from an XDocument but the value for the parent node is set to null, therefore when calling fragment.Remove(), I'm getting a SystemInvalidOperation error saying that 'parent is missing'.

I'm traversing a .wxs file which is loaded into an XDocument, and within this file there is a Wix root, and XProcessingInstruction nodes containing nested XElements containing a collection of DescendantNodes().

```
<Wix>
  <?if condition ?>
  <Fragment>
    ....
  </Fragment>
  <?endif?>
</Wix>
```

I've tried removing the `<?if condition ?>` and `<?endif?>` first which works because `<Wix>` is their parent node, but I keep receiving the error for `<Fragment>` regardless of if I delete it before or after the XProcessingInstructions.

How do I remove the fragment element properly?

Comment: Could you please post the code that's doing the removal?

Comment: Wix is the Fragment's parent node also.

Comment: Wix is the fragment's parent node but within Visual Studio debugger it isn't showing Wix as the value to the parent property

Comment: @DarthVeyda the problem was that I was parsing the current element being iterated over and storing it in an XElement so the parent property value ended up being null

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing your problem.  Consider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?if condition ?>
  <Fragment></Fragment>
</Wix>
```

This code:

```
    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi";
    string xmlTest = File.ReadAllText("test.wxs");
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlTest);
    doc.Descendants(ns + "Fragment").First().Remove();
    Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Outputs:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?if condition ?>
</Wix>
```

Comment: the problem was that I was parsing and storing the current element being iterated over in another XElement variable, so the parent value was null. When I did .Remove() on the temporary variable within the foreach loop, it was removed without issue